# Change variable sent to view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

in `__construct()` in my controller I sent some data to my view by:

```
public function __construct(){
    // code
    View::share('messages',$messages);
    // more code
}
```

In other method I want to change this value (action from user change it). I don't want to copy this part of code to every method in controller because code is not clear in my opinion.

Can I use something like:

```
View()->get('param');
```

If you have any ideas so please answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a previously shared variable with `shared()`:

```
view()->shared('param');
```

Comment: [Use the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php#L846-L856) ;)

Comment: Okay, I will try it :)